# Why can't I call setTitle on UIButton with multiple UIControlStates?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uilabel

I just spent a few hours finding out that

```
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: [.normal, .selected])
```

is not the same as:

```
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .selected)
```

When using more then one `UIControlState` in the `setTitle` function, my titles would never show up and be set to nil when i checked them out. There were ways of accessing them from titleLabel, but results were quite weird through tons of troubleshooting.
I tried a billion things playing with `titleLabel`, `currentTitle`, `isHidden`, `isSelected`, and more, but I finally found out the only thing I had to change to make things work was to split that one line into multiple lines.

My question is, why does it work this way?

Comment: I think it also worked few years ago by using the way you initially tried... But it seems it's not working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton().setTitle(String?, for: UIControlState)
```

The setTitle method accepts the title you want to set along with the UIControlState you want to set it for.
Since UIControlState conforms to OptionSet datatype it accepts an array of UIControlState.

The idea is that for the states which you want to set a specific title you set them individually and for the rest it will simply use the title that was set for the normal state. In your case all you need to do is...

```
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
```

In case you want to set a different title for some of the states,

```
// buttonTitle1 for all the states 
button.setTitle(buttonTitle1, for: .normal)

// buttonTitle2 for the specified state
button.setTitle(buttonTitle2, for: .selected)
```

Comment: This is right. There's no need to set the *same* title for the normal state and any other state -- just set the title for `normal` and set any other titles for states that need titles different from the normal state. It'd be strange to use the same title for two non-normal states, such as `highlighted` and `disabled`.